# Hexagon Area given Width

Tags: geometry, puzzle

A convex hexagon, with parallel opposite sides has three different widths [distance between opposite parallel sides]. Given widths A,B and C, what is the hexagons area, in a general form that works for unequal A,B and C?

The constraints of parallel opposite sides means that each opposite side is of equal length, but I have been unable to use this information to determine area.

Comment: Opposite sides being parallel does not mean that they are equal, and even if we enforce that as a separate requirement, the three widths will not give you the area. Wait, are you by any chance thinking of a hexagon with fixed _angles_? But no, even that would not help.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You are correct that the side lengths do not need to be equal. Thank you for pointing that out. In this case though, as another constraint they are.

Comment: That's still not enough.

Comment: @achillehui But if it were a very very thin hexagon, one of the widths would be much much smaller. I do not see how two hexagons with the same three widths, with opposite sides of equal length can have two different areas.

Comment: @Asimov oic, i misunderstand the constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: three widths fixed]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: Thank you for the visual example.